# For sensing continuous Voltage and deamplifier circuit?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, voltage-measurement

Basically, OpAmp is used for the purpose of the amplifying the voltage in the circuit and in the circuit below, i supplied 10v and it is deamplified to 1A. The ratio of attenuation is 0.1. The circuit[image] is posted below and the the supply to opamp is 15 v and 5 v is supplied to pin 3 through 220k. My question is that how the deamplifing comes into the role even though the formula contradicts (i.e 1 + R2/R1) and where the power is lost ?

Comment: That circuit is a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR1ll0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Redrawn circuit split into three sections.*

Redrawing the circuit can often clarify what is going on. In your case you have three sections:

- A potential divider consisting of R3 and R4. The "gain" of this stage is \$ \frac {R4}{R3+R4} = \frac {220k}{1220k} = 0.18\$.
- A non inverting op-amp with gain given by \$ (1 + \frac {R1}{R2}) = (1 + \frac {220k}{1000k}) = 1.22\$.
- Another potential divider with "gain" of \$ \frac {R5}{R5+R6} = \frac {10k}{20k} = 0.5\$.

The "gain" of the whole circuit is the product of all three gains.

$$ G = 0.18 \times 1.22 \times 0.5 = 0.1098$$

Comment: Wow, such a great explanation. Takes only few minutes to go through what exactly it is. Kudos, great tutor you are. Tx a lot.

Comment: @DaveTweed: Thanks for the edit. Rushed answers aren't good!